# Overloaded operator for C++ class doesn't get called

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In my class, I write the prototype (public) as:

```
bool operator< (const MyClass& obj);
```

I implement the method outside the class (in the same file) as:

```
bool MyClass::operator< (const MyClass& obj)
{
    cout << "operator< used" << endl;
    //do my work
}
```

The problem is that although my overloading operator gets called if I call it explicitly (like `obj1->operator<(*obj2)`) but not when called implicitly (like `obj1 < obj2`).

I have followed overloading tutorial from [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) and I can't see what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`obj1` and `obj2` are pointers, so you do `*obj1 < *obj2`.

Comment: I'd also expect it to be free.

Answer (score 1):

obj1 and obj2 are pointers to MyClass.
if you want to call operator < use:
*obj1 < *obj2